# reading ipv6 instead of IPv4 in PHP

Tags: php, ipv6, ipv4

When my PHP website reads my visitor IP address it shows in the IPv4 format.

However when I go to a third party site (such as https://www.whatismyip.com/) my visitor address shows an IPv6 format.

How do I get my PHP website to read/listen for/display the longer IPv6 format of the visitor IP address?

Comment: you'd only get that if someone visited your site using ipv6. if they're connecting with ipv4, there will be NO ipv6 address to capture, and vice versa. just because YOU are capable of using ipv6 doesn't mean THEY are as well...

Comment: To build on what @MarcB said, that's why its `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` instead of something like:  `$_SERVER['REMOTE_IPV4']`

Comment: So...someone visiting my site needs to be connected using ipv6.

That makes sense.

So why do I see two different IP addresses if I go to two sites (mine and whatismyip.com) and one gives me an ipv4 address and the other gives ipv6?

Comment: Here is what I see: http://imgur.com/ZGQtKv5

Comment: because you connected to the "mine" site with ipv4 for whatever reason, and ipv6 with the whatismyip one. even if your server is configured for ipv6, all of the routers between you and that server have to support ipv6 as well, or be using an ipv6-over-v4 tunnel

Comment: Thanks, Marc. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get IPv4 addresses in IPv6 format this is probably because your webserver is listening for all requests (IPv4 and IPv6) on a single IPv6 interface. In that case when it reads the peer address it always gets an address in IPv6 format resulting IPv4 addresses to be mapped by prepending ::ffff: to the IPv4 address.

So this is a configuration of your webserver and not of PHP.

If you want to have the IPv4 addresses in that format, you can just prepend the IPv4 address with the fixed string "::ffff:". But why would you want to do this?

Also you will always get the IP address for the IP version you used to connect to the server. So when you wonder why you don't get a real (not a mapped) IPv6 address it's probably because your browser connected to the server using IPv4. Either because your server is not able to listen to IPv6 requests or because its IPv6 connectivity is much slower than the IPv4 connectivity. In that case browsers often fall back to use IPv4 to provide better performance to their user.

Comment: I'm starting to understand. I thought if you were connected via IPv6, then all websites would be able to see the IPv6 address.

Note: I wanted the true IPv6 if available because it would give me a more accurate reading of the end users location.

Comment: If you want the IPv6 addresses of your users: update your server to support connections by IPv6. Therefore you need IPv6 connectivity and an AAAA entry for your domain in the DNS.
To make sure dual users connect by IPv6 you can also use a subdomain only accessible via IPv6 and connect to this using a JavaScript snippet in your page.

Comment: Thank you! Holy cow. This is what I have been looking for:

• "update your server to support connections by IPv6"
• "IPv6 connectivity"
• "an AAAA entry for your domain in the DNS". 
• "To make sure dual users connect by IPv6 you can also use a subdomain only accessible via IPv6 and connect to this using a JavaScript snippet in your page."

I knew there was a way.